# Use Laravel HTTP Client With x-api-key token

Tags: laravel

I want to call an API with a x-api-key authentification parameter.

I'm use to do this with a normal Bearer Authentification :

```
$response = Http::withToken('APITOKEN')->post($endPoint, [
            'param1' => 'value1']);
```

But with the x-api-token i don't know how to do. I tryied this :

```
$response = Http::withHeaders(['x-api-key' => 'APITOKEN'])->withToken('APITOKEN')->post($endPoint, [
            'param1' => 'value1']);
```

But doesn't works :/

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I realized you solved this already, but I'm not able to reproduce the issue, not knowing which class `Http` refers to. Are you sure this is part of Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : Actually it works ! i just did a mistake with the token.

It possible to make it more simple :

```
$response = Http::withHeaders(['x-api-key' => 'APITOKEN'])->post($endPoint, [
            'param1' => 'value1']);
```